# Incomplete summary statistics in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, statistics, summarizing

I am using ArcMap 10.4.

I have an attribute table of shapefile with more than 20 millions rows stored in gdb. That table has a column with postcodes (that are often repeated) and column with values. I want to sum all values that refer to each unique postcode and for that I used Summary Statistics toolbox. But something went wrong. As result I have values for 2426 postcodes, when I know that there are 4709. Half of the values are missing in statistics table.

Does anybody know how to solve this or might know what has happened?

Comment: It's not possible to store a shapefile in a geodatabase -- they are two different formats. Do you mean you have a 20m row feature class in a geodatabase? Generally the attributes are considered to be part of the feature class with the geometry (one table), unless you have a standalone related table.

Comment: Yes, thank you for your correction, it was a mistake. I have a feature class with 20 m rows and still have a problem mentioned above.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with that clarification.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of the Summary Statistics window to show the settings you use?

Answer (score 2):

The answer below was based on the question stating that there appeared to be 2,000 records in the table.  Although that now turns out not to be the case (it is 2,426), and this answer will therefore not help this asker, I'll leave the answer here in case it helps a future visitor lookin for possible reasons why they see only exactly 2,000 records in a table or feature class.

---

I suspect that the reason for this is the same as in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/195616/115) to [Only able to view 2000 records of Excel table using ArcMap](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/195555/115):

> ArcMap has traditionally used 2000 records as their standard cache
>   amount from a table. When you load in a table, and this used to apply
>   to shapefiles as well, it would do a first read of the table. If there
>   were more than 2000 records, it would load the first 2k, and show 
>   `0 of *2000 Selected` at the bottom.

If you click the button to go to the last record then I think you will see all records loaded.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I've already tried that. The last record is 2000, and it doesn't show me 0 of *2000.

Comment: Are there exactly 2000 out of exactly 4000 or only about 2000 out of about 4000?  I think that's an important detail to edit into your question.

Comment: Actualy, there are 2426 of 4709.